# Collection nested inside Tracer

Tags: dictionary, trace

I want to write custom tracer adding functionality to track duration (time spent on execution) of some routine.
I am thinking about using `Dictionary<object, DateTime>`.

Here is a pseudo code:

```
// adding current time to the dictionary for key 'anyObject'
Tracer.SaveCurrentTime(anyObject);
// doing something
// adding related line to a log file and removing key 'anyObject'and its value from the dictionary
Tracer.TraceTimeSpent(anyObject);
```

At first I liked it because this approach would work for different threads and classes.
But now I am wondering if it is a good idea at all? Calling `SaveCurrentTime` without calling `TraceTimeSpent` would leave key/value pair in the dictionary until the end of the process execution.

It is a bad practice and I will regret using it in my applications?

Comment: Side note: Adding language tag is generally good idea as there are about 700 people "watching" tags you've used compared to C# with its 629K watchers...

Comment: Overall your question is mostly opinion based - no one knows if that approach would work for *your application*. And as with most "I'll write another logging framework" it's mostly of entertainment value... (at very least you should consider how that would behave if "anyObject" actually implements `GetHashCode` screwing up all your results)